# Is multiplication available between ciphertexts with different slots' numbers?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Suppose we have two ciphertexts c1 and c2.
c1 is generated based on the param whose slots are 1024.
c2 is generated based on the param whose slots are 512.
Then is multiplication available between c1 and c2?
If not, can we shrink c1 to have 512 slots? If we can shrink, how to shrink? Any ideas, steps or references? The only element I want to keep is the first element(value).

BR

Comment: Maybe it's just me but this question needs work. Define your terms to begin with

Comment: @kodlu: neither do I understand the question, but at least "slot" is attested in [some homomorphic encryption context](https://yongsoosong.github.io/files/slides/ECC18.pdf).

Comment: The problem is that the number of slots is defined by $m$, the degree of the cyclotomic polynomial, and $p$, the plaintext modulus. So, if they have different number of slots, what are you considering to be different in the two parameter sets? $m$ or $p$?